# Set default fill & stroke colors in Raphael.js

Tags: svg, raphael

Is it possible to set a default fill and stroke color in Raphael so that I don't have to specify it every time I create a new shape?

Comment: Could you just set some css on the svg, or elements, like svg { fill: blue; } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [set](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set) and apply the colours to the set

```
var st = paper.set();
st.push(
    paper.circle(10, 10, 5),
    paper.circle(30, 10, 5)
);
st.attr({fill: "red"}); // sets the fill of both circles
```